# psycopg2 ProgrammingError on server python but not on Mac python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have a python script that uses psycopg2 to make some SQL queries. When testing this locally on my mac everything works as expected. When running the script on a server (the intended destination) I get an error from psycopg2:

> .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/extras.py", line 120, in execute
>       return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
>   psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "0"
>   LINE 4: ...ice) OVER (ORDER BY time_series DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWIN...

The query works totally fine in pgadmin and on my local machine. In all cases I am using python 2.7. Here is the problem script:

```
def chart_files_price_movavg(itemname, hostname, port, dbname, username, pw):
    "itemname, db credentials"
    #creates a csv with average price per day with headers

    query = ("""SELECT time_series,
    avg_price AS daily_price,
    CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (ORDER BY time_series) > 7 
        THEN avg(avg_price) OVER (ORDER BY time_series DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 6 FOLLOWING)
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS avg_price

        FROM 
    (SELECT to_char(closing_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS time_series, SUM(price) / COUNT(itemname) AS avg_price
    FROM auction_prices 
    WHERE itemname = 'iphone6_16gb' AND price < 1000
    GROUP BY time_series) 
    AS foo""") % locals()

    filename = itemname + '_price_movavg.csv'

    filepath = '/home5/easypea9/public_html/downloads/' + filename
    #filepath = '/Users/Ali Mac Pro/Google Drive/Auto-Stock-Analysis/Python/Web Scraping/eBay/chartdata/' + filename

    copy_select(query, filepath, hostname, port, dbname, username, pw)
```

Updating psycopg2 didnt solve the issue, so I'm looking for new ideas.

[edit] 
and here is the copy_select() function

```
def copy_select(query, filename, hostname, port,  dbname, user, password):
    'query, outputfile, hostname, port, dbname, user, password'

    #global cur

    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(

            database=dbname,
            user=user,
            host=hostname,
            password=password)

        connection.autocommit = True
        cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    except:

        print 'database connection FAIL'


    ticquery = datetime.now()

    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    tocquery = datetime.now()
    querytime = tocquery - ticquery

    #write the csv
    openfile = open(filename, 'wb')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(openfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
    openfile.close()


    return rows
```

Comment: What version is your PostgreSQL server? The `<value> FOLLOWING` syntax was added in 9.0. Compare [8.4 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) and [9.0 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

Comment: version 8.4.20 on the sever and 9.4 locally, could be the source of the issues, will investigate.

Comment: So our PostgreSQL server host will charge us $300 just to upgrade to version 9.4 so I am now looking for help with translating the SQL query so it is compatible with version 8. I was way out of my comfort zone in writing the query in the first place! so really appreciate any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to 9.4. It's difficult (if not impossible) to do a moving average calculation with 8.4, which is the whole reason why they added the `PRECEDING`/`FOLLOWING` syntax. You can try posting a separate question about it. Alternatively, you can try to implement the moving average in Python, but that's out of the scope of this question.